# Multiple callers waiting on long running GET, any way to make them all wait on the same return?

Tags: c#, wcf, rest

I am running a WCF REST service and have discovered a bit of a bottleneck. Essentially the current code boils down to the below:

```
private static List<Widget> widgets;  

public async Task<List<SearchResult>> Search(string term)
{
    if(widgets == null) {
        // This call takes up to 60 seconds
        widgets = await GetWidgets();
    }
    return SearchUtil.Search(term, widgets);
}
```

The problem is that many requests can enter the if check and call this very long running operation. Instead, I want any additional incoming requests to essentially wait on that original call to complete and only one call to GetWidgets() is made. How can I achieve this so I stop firing off many requests when the dictionary is empty?

As a small aside, is it safe to assume this List/Dictionary will remain populated for the entire time the service is alive? Or could it empty for some reason? What is the best way to handle this type of situation (I'm guessing some other mechanism to cache)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a cache that never expires and populated the first time someone requests the value. This should be pretty straightforward to build in a generic way:

```
class NonExpiringLazyLoadingCache<T>
{
    private readonly Func<Task<T>> _factory;
    private Task<T> _retrievalTask;
    private readonly object _lockObject = new object();

    public NonExpiringLazyLoadingCache(Func<Task<T>> factory)
    {
        this._factory = factory;
    }

    public async Task<T> GetValue()
    {
        lock (this._lockObject)
            if (this._retrievalTask == null)
                this._retrievalTask = this._factory();

        await this._retrievalTask;
        return this._retrievalTask.Result;
    }
}
```

Key things to note are that the `Task<T>` `await` will immediately return when the task is already completed, it is thread safe; the task is guaranteed to be executed only once.

Usage:

```
 private static NonExpiringLazyLoadingCache<List<Widget>> cache = new NonExpiringLazyLoadingCache<List<Widget>>(GetWidgets);
 ...
 var widgets = await cache.GetValue();
```

As for the duration of the object's lifetime, it depends on where your WCF service is hosted. It usually stays as long as the process stays alive, for IIS hosted services the value will be cleared when the Application Pool is recycled.

Answer (score 1):

This is not entirely possible without providing a mechanism that is thread safe to lock the widgets object until the first request is complete. As WCF services are asynchronous many requests can start calling the `widgets = await GetWidgets();` method at once.

I would suggest a simply lock such as:

```
private static List<Widget> widgets;  
static readonly object _widgetsLock = new object();

public async Task<List<SearchResult>> Search(string term)
{
    if(widgets == null) {
        // This call takes up to 60 seconds
        lock(_widgetsLock)
             if(widgets == null)
                  widgets = await GetWidgets();
    }
    return SearchUtil.Search(term, widgets);
}
```

Simply locked the `_widgetsLock` object which will stop all other execution through the lock method until the `lock` is released. Now  once the lock is released if there is a waiting thread to access that code it double checks if the `widgets` are infact still null (a previous attempt may have loaded it).

You could also load the Widgets at application startup before your application starts handling requests.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't have an 'Await' inside the body of a lock. I have found some ways to accomplish something similar though.